# Can email retrieved by Gmail via POP3 from a different provider be tagged with a specific label?

Tags: gmail, pop3

If I configure Gmail to retrieve mail from a different provider via POP3, can the *retrieved messages be identified in a unique way* in a filter to be tagged with a specific label e.g. "pop3"?

I am aware of `deliveredto:` but I cannot use it in this case because it is not specific enough for a catchall custom domain that also sometimes forwards to the same Gmail account (yes, it is an unusual setup but let's not discuss that part in this question).

Comment: That is one of the options presented when you set up POP3 retrieval in Gmail (Label Incoming Messages).  Have you made any effort to resolve this on your own by searching this forum or the Internet? https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/21289?hl=en&ref_topic=9283043#zippy=%2Cstep-change-your-gmail-settings

Comment: [@Blind Spots](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/197518/blind-spots) thank you for your answer, no I did not find that screen recording on my own and do not recall the option to label being there when I set up pop3 long time ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Add Label When Adding Account

1. In a web browser go to Gmail ([link to Gmail](https://mail.google.com/))
2. In the top right, click on the Settings icon [image: Settings Cog] and then click "See all settings" ([link to Gmail #settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/general))
3. Click on Accounts and Import ([link to Gmail #accounts](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/accounts))
4. Click **Add a mail account** in the section **Check mail from other accounts**
5. Type in the **email address** for your POP3 account and click **Next**
6. select the radio button labelled **Import emails from my other account (POP3)** and click **Next**
7. Fill in the **Username**, **Password**, **POP Server**, and **Port** for your POP3 account.
8. Check the box labelled **Label incoming messages** and choose the default label (POP address) or customize.
9. Check/uncheck any other options as applicable.
10. Click **Add Account** button.

### Add Label After Adding Account

1. In a web browser go to Gmail ([link to Gmail](https://mail.google.com/))
2. In the top right, click on the Settings icon [image: Settings Cog] and then click "See all settings" ([link to Gmail #settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/general))
3. Click on Accounts and Import ([link to Gmail #accounts](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/accounts))
4. In the section **Check mail from other accounts** click on the **edit info** link to the right of the account that you wish to modify.
5. Add a check to the box labelled **Label incoming messages** and choose the default label (POP address) or customize.
6. Check/uncheck any other options as applicable.
7. Save changes.